# Send a data of type 'short' to another end of serial connection

Tags: java, android, serial-port

I have this data:

```
byte STX = (byte) 0xFA;
```

When I send this thru my serial connection, the receiving end correctly interprets the data as `0xFA`. My question is, isn't `byte` supposed to carry data from -128 to 127 only? Doing the cast to `byte` in my code above should result to a loss of information right? How is it possible that the receiving end still receives the correct information?

Comment: Try to convert 0xFA to decimal, using [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Comment: Or, more trivially, try `System.out.println((byte)0xFA);`